# sending and receiving emails with GCP

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform, postfix-mta

I'm switching from a shared hosting provider to GCP. I have a domain name (domain.com), and on the shared hosting I just had to create a new email address in the directadmin panel, and use squirrelmail to send/receive emails.

The problem is: I don't know how to achieve this on GCP.

I have added a new zone in cloud DNS for the domain name, and I have changed the nameservers of the domain name at my hosting provider (where the domain name is parked).

Now I'm looking for a solution so I can use the domain name (coupled to a VM) but also send/receive emails in an easy way.

Is there a (paid/free) solution I can use which isn't very difficult to install/maintain? I was thinking of creating a mailserver with postfix/postfixadmin, but GCP blocks outgoing mail so I have to use a service like sendgrid or mailgun to send email + I still need to install postfix for receiving email. But to be honest: I've never done this before and I don't find any good tutorials about this.

I have a mailgun account and I tried following this (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun) tutorial, but the emails I'm sending are not delivered.

Is there an online service or something like that where I can couple my domain name to, to send and receive emails? I tried to google it, I googled on "external mail server" and "free mail server" but I didn't find any (good) results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Software suggestions are off-topic, 2. This would be better on ServerFault, for example. 3. Why do you need GCP? Choose a platform that allows outgoing mail. I'm surprised GCP doesn't allow it.. are you sure? Dovecot + postfix are great for basic mail servers. And they're free.

Comment: Some real world advice. Do not setup your own mail server. Use an established email service such as G Suite, Office 365, etc. Today, email is judged by your IP address reputation which will be zero for the first few months. Your email will be blocked or go to the Junk folder if you set up your own email server.

Comment: @JohnHanley: thank you for your advice. I started using GSuite a couple hours ago. It works perfectly and I can still use my domain name.

Comment: G Suite is a good choice.

Comment: For transactional emails, which is what you're handling when your application sends emails for activities on your website, you started correctly by trying to use Sendgrid/Mailgun etc. You may be able to find help on ServerFault on the issues you had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailgun sounds like a good option to use, if you're still planning to use it on GCP, check that you've created a firewall rule to allow outbound traffic [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail#email_custom_port). This step might be the reason why you're not receiving the emails.

If you need a good guide to set up a Postfix server, you might find this guide useful [[2]](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/).

I've read that you're already using G Suite [[3]](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/es-419_mx/products/gmail/), this option is great and will ease the process a lot.